# How to add extra constraint to table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, primary-key, unique-key

This my table:

```
customer_id
user_id
password
email
first_name
last_name
```

My primary key is `customer_id` which is generated by the system. How can I prevent a user form creating multiple accounts?

Should I put a constrain on another column?

Comment: Maybe don't allow users to have same email?

Comment: What's user_id ? Add at least a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique index or constraint on however you identify the user.  I'm not sure which columns you have in mind, but this would be typical:

```
alter table mytable add constraint unq_table_email unique (email);
```

You can have more than one unique constraint on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't have a username field so u can do is that you can make email field as unique.  What I do is that I make email id unique and whenever user tries to register i check whether email id is present. Because email id is unique no two person can have same email id.